# LibGDX: setPosition() not working in Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, positioning, scene2d

I'm trying to position a group of actors using the setPosition() method. I want to center the group in the screen continuosly while I'm adding actors, that is to say, I add one actor, the group is centered with one actor; I add a second actor, the group centers again but now with two actors, and so on. I use the next operation to do this:

```
Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - submitGroup.getMinWidth()) / 2 // Height is 0.
```

Group's minwidth is the sum of actors width. On desktop works perfect, but in Android doesn't make any effect and I don't know why. It doesn't center as I expected and I'm confused. Here is my code and two screenshots(desktop and android).

```
a.setSize(50, 50);
b.setSize(50, 50);
c.setSize(50, 50);
submitGroup = new HorizontalGroup();
submitGroup.addActor(a);
submitGroup.addActor(b);
submitGroup.addActor(c);
submitGroup.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - submitGroup.getMinWidth()) / 2, 0);
submitGroup.align(Align.bottom);
stage.addActor(submitGroup);
```

[image: Desktop]

[image: Android]

As it can see in the second one, the actors are not centered. My game is 800x480. What's going on? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `submitGroup.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - submitGroup.getMinWidth()/ 2, 0)`

Comment: It's the same operation. Distributive property.

Comment: True, my answer was lame. Your answer below indeed tackles the problem. From device to device the screen resolution changes so if you add your actors on a 800x480 viewport in your code, then this 800x480 viewport will be stetched to the device's resolution automatically (e.g will stretch to 1920 x 1080). As a result we should get viewport height and width to substract the actors position since we added the actor to this virtual resolution of 800x480. Then Libgdx will automatically stretch everything correctly to each device's resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved changing `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` for `800`. Why this?

Because I'm using a `ScalingViewport` of `800x480` and it's associated with my stage. So, this viewport shows the region as I indicated in the constructor, that is to say, I didn't create a ScalingViewport with screen's height and screen's width. Therefore, I have to take the viewport's size, not screen's size.

I hope this helps someone. I would appreciate any comments or improving this answer.

Comment: Ah, so you needed to use the world's coordinates and not the screen coordinates. I ran into that once, because the viewport is handled slightly differently on the two places - albeit I was using the viewport and orthogonal transform manually, not with the scene2d version.

Comment: Exactly. I'm using Scene2D because I think that it will help me a lot managing objects. Nevertheless, I'm not quite sure, I'm still learning about LibGDX. Thanks for your comment!